# Part of as string from a string using regular expressions

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string of  5 characters out of which the first two characters should be in some list and next three should be in some other list.

How could i validate them with regular expressions?

Example:

- List for First two characters `{VBNET, CSNET, HTML)}`
- List for next three characters `{BEGINNER, EXPERT, MEDIUM}`

My Strings are going to be: `VBBEG`, `CSBEG`, etc.

My regular expression should find that the input string first two characters could be either VB, CS, HT and the rest should also be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following expression work for you in a more general case (so that you don't have hardcoded values): `(^..)(.*$)`
- returns the first two letters in the first group, and the remaining letters in the second group.

Comment: Thanks for that. My First two characters extracted should match the first two characters of the word in the list specified. Any threads on this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Rupesh The list matching would depend on what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

something like [this](http://regexr.com?30lp4):

```
^(VB|CS|HT)(BEG|EXP|MED)$
```

Answer (score 1):

This recipe works for me:

```
^(VB|CS|HT)(BEG|EXP|MED)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `(VB|CS|HT)(BEG|EXP|MED)` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are as well-defined as this, you don't even need regex - simple string slicing would work.

For example, in Python we might say:

```
mystring = "HTEXP"

prefix = mystring[0:2]
suffix = mystring[2:5]

if (prefix in ['HT','CS','VB']) AND (suffix in ['BEG','MED','EXP']):
    pass # valid!
else:
    pass # not valid. :(
```

Don't use regex where elementary string operations will do.

Comment: @Rupesh: A regexp can certainly be used to solve this problem - in this case the complexity of the code is about the same. My general advice, however, is to think carefully before using regular expressions for *everything*. Often "plain" string methods will do just fine.